# Why does the simpler way to computing the Gini coefficient work?

Tags: proof-writing

The Gini coefficient is often used in economics to calculate inequality.

According to [this website](https://www.statsdirect.com/help/nonparametric_methods/gini_coefficient.htm), the formula for calculating Gini coefficient is

$G = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} |x_i - x_j|}{2n^2\bar{x}}$

However, if all values are arranged in ascending order, computation is quicker:

$G = \frac{2}{n^2\bar{x}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}i(x_i-\bar{x})$

Why does the last formula work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first formula has no $i=j$ contributions and is a sum of $i\leftrightarrow j$-symmetric terms, so can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{n^2\bar{x}}\sum_{i>j}(x_i-x_j)$ if we adopt the convention $i>j\to x_i>x_j$. It suffices to prove $\sum_{i>j}(x_i-x_j)=2\sum_i (ix_i -i\bar{x})$. The term $x_i$ appears on the left-hand side $i-1-(n-i)=2i-1-n$ times, and on the right-hand side $2(i-\sum_i \frac{i}{n})=2i-\frac{2T_n}{n}$ times where $T_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is the $n$th triangle number. You can verify these coefficients agree.